# Can the Ant task "patch" be used in Linux for patching files with DOS linefeeds?

Tags: linux, ant, newline, patch, line-endings

How can we...

1. use the Ant task [patch](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/patch.html) in Linux for patching files with DOS linefeeds?
2. apply the command line option `--binary` with the Ant task [patch](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/patch.html)?

See the details below.

### Files

- [build.xml](https://github.com/haba713/ant_patch_crlf/blob/master/build.xml): Ant build file with a patch task
- [test.patch](https://github.com/haba713/ant_patch_crlf/blob/master/test.patch): patch file with DOS linefeeds
- [test.txt](https://github.com/haba713/ant_patch_crlf/blob/master/test.txt): source file with DOS linefeeds

### Command line `patch` fails

DOS linefeeds in the patch file are converted into Unix linefeeds and patching
fails:

```
[0] mypc<u0>:~/src/test/ant_patch_crlf>patch -i test.patch
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file test.txt
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file test.txt.rej
```

### Command line `patch --binary` works fine

As suggested above

> `use --binary to disable`

adding the option `--binary` helps:

```
[0] mypc<u0>:~/src/test/ant_patch_crlf>patch --binary -i test.patch
patching file test.txt
```

### Ant task `patch` fails

Ant task `patch` fails with the same error than command line without the
option `--binary`:

```
[0] mypc<u0>:~/src/test/ant_patch_crlf>ant                              
Buildfile: /home/u0/src/test/ant_patch_crlf/build.xml

patch:
    [patch] (Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
    [patch] patching file test.txt
    [patch] Hunk #1 FAILED at 1 (different line endings).
    [patch] 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file test.txt.rej
    [patch] 'patch' failed with exit code 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: The Ant task is a wrapper for the path executable, hence the behaviour you observe.  The Ant task has no way to pass the --binary option through.  You might consider using the Ant exec task instead to wrap the command-line patch and include options you need.